# How To make Whatsapp Call Button in Webpage?

Tags: javascript, android, html, whatsapp

I want to add a WhatsApp call button in my webpage. When the users (Mostly Mobile users) click on this button, it will be open WhatsApp and make a call (or WhatsApp ask for a call)

I Tried These codes:-

```
<a href="whatsapp://0123456789" target="_BLANK" >Contact Us</a>
<a href="whatsapp://call?number=0123456789" target="_BLANK" >Contact Us</a>
<a href="https://wa.me/0123456789" target="_BLANK" >Contact Us</a>
```

some of them not working, and some of them using to chat. but i want to call via whatsapp. as like as `tel:0123456789` do in regular phone call.

Comment: as far as I know, there is no such thing. only click chat links are available.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=0123456789">Contact us</a>
```

Comment: that's cool, but doesn't call to the number. just for chatting.

Comment: I think WhatsApp Calling requires special permissions like microphone and camera in both IOS and Android. This makes the call feature only accessible while in the app. My thoughts though!!